# how to make resize UIImage from another UIImage

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uilabel

I have one image like this :

[image]

I want to put one UILabel in this image and set this image width with text width in my label.
please guide me how to resize this image from width (no height) set from text label in it!!!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @StephenDarlington I don't know about that

Comment: use popover controls.... for iphone third party control wepopover

Comment: So what's your question? Is it how do I find the width of a label? Is it how do I resize an image? Or is it can you please do my job?

Comment: @Spynet my friend I don't use popover for this...I want to use image for icon marker google maps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

Comment: my friend how to do it?

Comment: my friend how to use this?